# Response time from individual api request in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Flow:

```
API A is calling API B

Api B is calling C  

API C IS CALLING DB
```

How to find the response time from B to A?

In jmeter response time over time graph gives the over all response time.
I want to find the individual response.

Ex client calls a . A ll cal B, B ll call C, C will fetch the response from db and give to B within 5ms , B will give response to A within 5 ms and A will give to client within 5ms.

If I add response time over time graph I will see 15 ms but how do O find from b to a?

Comment: I assume you mean JMeter samplers here by API. To get avg. min/max response time of each sampler you should consult Summary results report.